# How to use values from this array? Ext-JS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

So, when I put `console.log(Test.globals.user)` I get this:

```
[id: "1", first_name: "MyFirstName", last_name: "MyLastName"]
```

How can I get values of first and last name? I've tried this:

```
Test.globals.user.first_name //undefined
Test.globals.user[first_name] //error - no first_name variable provided
Test.globals.user["first_name"] //undefined
```

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

The Ext way of doing it would be to have a singleton class to hold global, app wide vars:

```
Ext.define('Test.globals', {
    singleton: true,

    user: {
        id: 1,
        first: 'Foo',
        last: 'Bar'
    }
});

Ext.onReady(function(){
    console.log(Test.globals.user.first);
});
```

Not Ext example

```
var Test = {
    globals: {
        user: {
            first: 'Foo'
        }
    }    
};
```

Comment: Show how you're declaring it, as opposed to what the console outputs.

Comment: Test.globals.user = []; Test.globals.user.firstName and Test.globals.user.lastName.

Comment: So you don't want it to be an array, you want it to be a key/value map?

Comment: I don't care what it is. I just need those values. Can I get them somehow with the current declaration? Btw. thank you very much for helping. Appreciate it. :)

Comment: Updated OP with an example.

Comment: Thank you but then I'll have to change a whole bunch of my application. What will be the "way" if I've used ONLY JS without Ext. :)

Comment: Not sure why you would tag the question Ext and then ask for it not to be used, seems kind of odd. Anyway, updated OP.

Comment: Hi Evan, is there any downside or reason why do you omit a example with Ext.namespace?

Comment: Not really, Ext.ns() doesn't get used much now since define() has become the way to create classes.

Answer (score 0):

can you try Test.globals.user[1].first_name?